# Variadic Templates, std::function and lambdas as class members

Tags: templates, lambda, c++17, variadic-templates, std-function

I have a couple of classes here the first being a class that stores `std::function` type.

```
template<typename RES_TYPE, typename... ARG_TYPES>
struct Functor {
    std::function<RES_TYPE( ARG_TYPES... )> call_back;
};
```

I have another class that will register an incoming function either from a function object, function pointer or a lambda and stores an instance of the class above and has another member function that will invoke it.

```
template<typename RES_TYPE, typename... ARG_TYPES>
class Driver {
private:
    Functor<RES_TYPE, ARG_TYPES...> callback_;

public:
    Driver() = default;
    ~Driver() = default;

    void register_callback( const Functor<RES_TYPE, ARG_TYPES...> &func ) {
        callback_ = func;
    }

    RES_TYPE call_back( ARG_TYPES... args ) {
        return callback_( args... );
    }    
};
```

I'm struggling to get the syntax right to where I'm trying to pass in the values of the function when trying to invoke it. My main looks something like this:

```
int main() {    
    Functor<int, int, int> func;
    auto lambda = []( int a, int b ) { return a + b; };
    func.call_back = lambda;

    Driver<int, int, int> driver;
    driver.register_callback( func );
    std::cout << driver.call_back( 3, 5 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I can not seem to wrap my head around what I'm missing within the syntax. I've tried various other things but with this current setup as is I'm getting this compiler error from Visual Studio 2017 CE:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Temp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\...\main.cpp(62): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments
1>c:\...\main.cpp(62): note: while compiling class template member function 'RES_TYPE Driver<RES_TYPE,int,int>::call_back(int,int)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            RES_TYPE=int
1>        ]
1>c:\...\main.cpp(77): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'RES_TYPE Driver<RES_TYPE,int,int>::call_back(int,int)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            RES_TYPE=int
1>        ]
1>c:\...\main.cpp(75): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Driver<int,int,int>' being compiled
1>Done building project "Temp.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have an idea of what the compiler is telling me but I can not seem to get the syntax correct to store this lambda, then be able to invoke it. I'm trying to keep these classes as generic as possible so that it can accept lambdas, function objects or function pointers.

---

**Solution**

My code now looks like this and works fine!

```
template<typename RES_TYPE, typename... ARG_TYPES>
struct Functor {
    std::function<RES_TYPE( ARG_TYPES... )> func_;
};

template<typename RES_TYPE, typename... ARG_TYPES>
class Driver {
private:
    Functor<RES_TYPE, ARG_TYPES...> functor;

public:
    Driver() = default;
    ~Driver() = default;

    void register_callback( const Functor<RES_TYPE, ARG_TYPES...> &func ) {
        functor = func;
    }

    RES_TYPE call_back( ARG_TYPES... args ) {
        return functor.func_( args... );
    }    
};

int main() {    
    Functor<int, int, int> func;
    auto lambda = []( int a, int b ) { return a + b; };
    func.func_ = lambda;

    Driver<int, int, int> driver;
    driver.register_callback( func );
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    std::cout << driver.call_back( a, b ) << '\n';
    std::cout << driver.call_back( 7, 5 ) << '\n';

    Functor<void, std::string, std::string> func2;
    auto lambda2 = []( std::string str1, std::string str2 ) {
        str1 = str1 + " " + str2;
        std::cout << str1 << '\n';
    };

    Driver <void, std::string, std::string> driver2;
    func2.func_ = lambda2;
    std::string str1 = "Hello";
    std::string str2 = "World";
    driver2.register_callback( func2 );
    driver2.call_back( str1, str2 );
    driver2.call_back( "Generic", "Programming" );

    return 0;
}
```

> *Expected Outputs:*
>
> ```
> 8
> 12
> Hello World
> Generic Programming
> ```
>
> *Actual Outputs:*
>
> ```
> 8
> 12
> Hello World
> Generic Programming
> ```
>
> *Progam Exit:*
>
> ```
> Code (0)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to invoke `operator()(int, int)` on the `Functor` instance named `callback_`. Instead, you need to name the data member of this struct `call_back`. Like this:

```
RES_TYPE call_back( ARG_TYPES... args ) {
    return callback_.call_back( args... );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much: I new I was close; and was missing something trivial, but sometimes it's always good to have a second set of eyes around!

Comment: Yes I know about the forward referencing; but was trying to get rid of the compiler errors first!

Comment: And a data member called `callback_` that has a data member called `call_back` that needs to be called is indeed something to get easily wrong :)

Comment: Yes I do agree; I'll fix some of the naming conventions! Just trying to get the code to work as expected!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Not atm but I may change that to be so.

Comment: I may post a new question about the forward referencing.

Comment: Adding the `&&` to the function gave me other compiler errors, however leaving the function declaration above as it was but using `std::forward<ARG_TYPES>(args)...` worked without the `&&` on the function parameters. Not sure if this makes a difference though.

Comment: @FrancisCugler But that's a no-op. std::forward conditionally casts to an rvalue and shall be used for universal references exclusively. The second version in my answer should work, can you specify the compiler errors you encounter?

Comment: Yeah I figured it was a no-op, but when I changed the function signature the compiler is yelling at me that an `rvalue` can not be bound to a `lvalue`. I edited my original question to show you.

Comment: I also have another issue with the sets of classes too: If I try to create a different set of instances and I'm using `std::string` the code compiles and builds but when I run it; it crashes giving me an Exception Unhandled error: `std::bad_function_call`

Comment: I overlooked that the method `call_back` is in a non-deduced context... that means `ARG_TYPE&&...` does not name a universal references, but instead an rvalue reference, as the template argument types have already been specified upon class construction. My fault. I'll adjust the answer! Best is you also trim down your question to the original version, too.

Comment: I added another section with the crashing behavior when using `std::string` as argument types!

Comment: I think I found out my issue with the crash; I think I forgot to register the lambda: lol, I'm getting a little tired as it is getting a little late!

Comment: Yes, I forgot to register the lambda expression.